# GoFiber settings on ReadBufferSize

Tags: go, go-fiber

I can't find a way to increase the ReadBufferSize. I've attempted to increase it in the HostClient, but when I proceed with the request, the endpoint returns an error.

My code:

```golang
a := fiber.AcquireAgent()
a.HostClient = &fasthttp.HostClient{
    ReadBufferSize:  8192,
    WriteBufferSize: 8192,
}

fmt.Println("ReadBufferSize: ", a.ReadBufferSize)
req := a.Request()

req.Header.SetContentType("application/json")
req.Header.SetMethod("POST")
req.Header.Set("Authorization", key)
req.SetRequestURI(uri)

query := `{
    "query": "{ users { name email phone id } }"
 }`

req.SetBody([]byte(query))

_ = a.Parse()
status, body, errs := a.Bytes()
fmt.Println("Response Status Code:", status)
fmt.Println("Response Body:", string(body))
fmt.Println("Errors: ", errs)
```

fmt.Println("ReadBufferSize: ", a.ReadBufferSize) writes in console:
ReadBufferSize: 8192

Error from endpoint:
error when reading response headers: small read buffer. Increase ReadBufferSize. Buffer size=4096

Comment: Tried to set it on app.Server().ReadBufferSize = 8192, but result is the same. I am new to this, quite don't understand what's wrong with it. Also, looked at docs from fiber, there is no SetReadBufferSize or something. Internet says it should be on the server level...

Comment: Using same technique, I can set ReadBufferSize on http/net and fasthttp. But, I don't understand how to do so in fiber...

Comment: client := &fasthttp.Client{
  ReadBufferSize: 8192,
} 

works on fasthttp, why it does not on fiber though...